Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be integrable and uniformly continuous. Is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x f(x) = 0$?

If $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is a non-negative, uniformly continuous function which is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$, is it true that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{x_n} [f(x) - f(x_n)] dx$ whenever $x_n \uparrow \infty$? If so, conclude that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x f(x) = 0$.

First, we can show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = 0$ for all $x_n \uparrow \infty$. Indeed, if this is not true, that is, $\limsup_n f(x_n) = C > 0$, then suppose upon relabeling that $\lim_n f(x_n) = C > 0$. Then, for $n$ sufficiently large, $f(x_n) > C-\epsilon/2 > 0$, where $\epsilon > 0$ such that $C - \epsilon > 0$. By uniform continuity, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $|y - x_n| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x_n) \leq \epsilon/2 $. But then,  $f(y) > C - \epsilon$. Moreover, $\int f \geq \sum_n \int_{B_{\delta}(x_n)} f \geq \sum_n (C-\epsilon)\delta = \infty$, which is contradictory. Hence, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = 0$.
Now, note that the pointwise limit $\lim_{n} [f(x)  - f(x_n)]\chi_{[0,x_n]} =: \lim_n f_n(x) =  f$. Thus, $\int \lim f_n = \int f$. Thus, we'd like to commute integrals, i.e., say that $\lim_n \int f_n = \int f $.
I'm not sure how to do this, though. I tried to find a dominating function by reasoning that $|f_n| \leq [f(x) + f(x_n)] \chi_{[0,x_n]}(x)$, so that $\limsup_n |f_n| \leq f$, i.e., for all $N$ sufficiently large, $\sup_{n \geq N} |f_n(x)| \leq f$. But this seems incorrect to me, since I believe the $N$ depends on $x$, and also if we have equality of the $\limsup$, it may be that $\sup_{n \geq N} |f_n(x)| \downarrow f(x)$ (for ex., if $f(x) = 0$ is a root of $f$, and $f$ is only decreasing to $0$ in the limit)

Do you mean $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x f(x) = 0$? It is obviously false that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x f(x) = \infty$.

I'm so confused: What about any function $f$ which is eventually $=0$ ? Also your function is defined $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ or is it $f:[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty)$ ?

@geetha290krm I apologize for the typos, I've made all necessary corrections. It should be that $xf(x) \rightarrow 0$, not $\infty$.

@MaximilianJanisch typos adjusted, sorry! The function maps non-negative reals to non-negative reals

You missed the integral sign in $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [f(x) - f(x_n)] dx$

@geetha290krm apparently I hadn't made all corrections. Thanks again, its corrected!

It seems the conclusion is false.
For $n\in\mathbb N$, define the triangle function $f_n:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ as the piecewise linear function which is supported on $[n, n + 2/n]$, as
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x-n, &\text{if } x\in[n,n+1/n]\\ n+2/n-x, &\text{if }x\in[n+1/n,n+2/n].\end{cases}$$
Then define $f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n(x)$.
$f$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous and in particular uniformly continuous.
Furthermore, $f$ is integrable:
$$\int_0^\infty f \le \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \int_0^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty.$$
However, $$\mathrm{lim\ sup}_{x\to\infty} x f(x) = 1\neq 0.$$

PS: While trying to solve the problem, I prompted GPT-4o three times resulting in three incorrect proofs . https://chatgpt.com/share/c6cb3601-87ed-459e-835a-7c3b79e3a356

Thanks so much! Any reason why you suspected it to be false?

@algebroo Intuitively I thought that if a counter-example exists then there should be one with triangles. And the slope of the triangle sides should be bounded by a constant and the height of the $n$-th triangle should be at least on the order of $\frac 1n$ so to get a counter-example. This is what I tried and it worked. I wasn't sure it would be wrong from the start, I rather found out through construction of the counter-example .

@MaximilianJanisch I don't see why $f$ is 1-Lipschizt immediately, could you elaborate a bit more?

@JeffreyJao There is a finnicky direct proof, but I would say the easiest way to see it is that for $y\ge x$, we have $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert = \lvert\int_x^y g\rvert \le \int_x^y \lvert g\rvert\le y-x$, where $g$ is $1$ on all intervals $[n,n+1/n)$, where it is $-1$ on all intervals $(n+1/n, n+2/n]$, and where $g$ is $0$ everywhere else.
